# VBA for altering PowerPoint 2003 Presentations- Active not new

Tags: ms-access, vba, powerpoint

If I set up a template on PowerPoint slides, that contain all the text boxes I need, the what Visual Basic do I use to enter text that I want into those text boxes?

It is easier for me to use a template, because these ppt briefs contain (or need to contain) a lot of data:

- how do I enter text into those text boxes
- how do you alter the font, size, fontbold, etc of a particular text box?
- is there a way for determining the "name" of a text box/shape ("text box 52") other than recording macros after macros and selecting the text box, just to get the object name from selection?
- if I use a macro to determine the vba, why will it not work to use that as vba? the vb I get from a macro seems to have active.selection which just doesn't seem to work as a vba procedure because it doesn't know what to select???? i think

what i am looking to do is create the end game ppt from access, using the template. on an access form I want to have multiple text boxes that relay the information into the ppt text boxes on the slide.

i know how to launch a template (or new presentation) from access, and how to add new items (slides, graphs, charts, text) but I do not know how to alter pre-existing text boxes!!

Please help....my work is needing this like yesterday!

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access shapes by name, as in:

```
Dim oSlide As Slide
Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Dim oShape As Shape
Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(strShapeName)

Dim oTextRange As TextRange
Set oTextRange = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange

oTextRange.Text = "this is some text"

oTextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
```

Note that whatever you're looking to do, just record a macro of you doing it via the UI, and copy that. You're right that the recorded macro will use the `Selection` object a lot, but that's easily fixed - just get a reference to the appropriate `Shape` object (or whatever) and then subsitute that in the generated code.

So, for example, if the recorded macro for changing the fill color of a shape is this:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.Solid
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0#
End With
```

... and you want to apply the fill color to a shape which you already have a reference to as `oShape`, then change the code to this:

```
With oShape
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.Solid
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0#
End With
```

To get the current name of a shape, you can enter this in the "immediate" window in the VBA editor:

```
?ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
```

You could turn that into a (single) macro very easily:

```
Sub ShowMeTheName()
    MsgBox ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
End Sub
```

Note that I would personally rename the shapes to something meaningful rather than using the default names. Simply turn do this in the immediate window:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "MyName"
```

...or create a macro to prompt for a name.

Comment: wow...this is an excellent answer. besides the fact that you know what you were talking about, you broke it down for a hack like me!

thanks very much for the help!

Comment: So i used this and it worked fine, but I cannot alter more than one text box in a sub procedure. I tried by:

dim oShape1 as Shape 
dim oTextRange1 as TextRange, and so on so forth

but it is still only altering the first selected text box, with the second selected/written text string

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: oops nevermind...i missed one. got it now! thanks again this helps me getting going in the right direction big time!

Answer (score 0):

When I need to automate Word or Excel (nobody I know or work with has any use for PowerPoint), I open the app in question, turn on Macro recording and do the task I want to automate. Then I use the generated code as the basis for my Access code. It's often a pretty straightforward process, sometimes as simple as copying and pasting and then prefacing each line with the application object I'm using from Access.

If I had to do what you're doing, that's exactly how I'd start, by doing recording the task being performed interactively, and then experimenting with what part of the code is essential.

Comment: thanks. that is actually what i have been doing lately and it has worked fine on most things thus far. I simply did not know how to find out the name of the object in question and the above code solved that so I am off....

thanks guys!